# Visual Studio 2013 GitHub Commit Trouble

Tags: github, visual-studio-2013, commit, git-commit, checkin

I use GitHub for my MVC 4 project on Visual Studio. But some pages that I've added, I can't commit to GitHub.

You can see on the image, there are lock symbols for check-in, but others have not. I can commit the pages with lock symbols but I can't commit without lock symbol. How can I fix it? How can I commit these pages to GitHub?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should go to Team Explorer and watch Untracked Files section. All files that you add to your project should be there. You just need add them to commit.

[image: Untracked Files]

Comment: I found it by myself also. Thanks anyway. I thumbed up. ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I found the solution by myself.

[image: Click the "Changes" on Team Explorer panel]

[image: You can see which files are not on GitHub by "Untracked Files". Then you can commit them.]